# Why not all the Questions closely related to WordPress in StackOverflow migrated to WPSE?

Tags: discussion

[image: WordPress search in StackOverflow]

As now on Bangladesh time 20:25, the [topic/tag **#WordPress** in StackOveflow generates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) **39,820 threads**. Why not they are migrated to WordPress.StackExchange.com to let them shed some light, not from general WordPress experts, but from the purely-WordPress-enthusiasts?